# LoadError: cannot load such file - require_relative on modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have written an initializer in `config/initializers/my_ini` that has a `require_relative` statement: `require_relative "../../lib/ryze/ryze"`

I have the required file in `app/lib/ryze/ryze.rb`

However, now when I try to boot the app I get `LoadError: cannot load such file -- /app/lib/ryze/ryze` on the `require_relative` line of the initializer `my_ini`

Folder structure:

```
|-app
| |_config
|  |_initializers
|   |-my_ini.rb
|
|-lib
| |_ryze
|   |-ryze.rb
```

note: I am using this application in docker

What are some options I could try to debug this?

Comment: lib is not a child of app.  you need ```require_relative "../../../lib/ryze/ryze"```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I was trying to require my lib from inside the `app` folder, while in fact, the lib folder I was trying to reach should be in the same level as `app` not inside.

once I moved `lib` out, it worked!